# Regex capture groups of N and the remainder?

Tags: regex

Supposing, I have a string `ASDFZXCVQW`, is it possible to capture this into groups of N, and then the remaining characters would be in the final group.

For example, if N were 4, then we could have: `ASDF`, `ZXCV`, and `QW`. Notice how the QW is everything that is left over.

I know how to capture the groups of N with `.{N}`, and then manually get the leftover through string indexing, **but is it possible to do this in a single regular expression?**

Comment: Maybe `/.{1,4}/g`. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = 'ASDFZXCVQW'

var result = data.match(/\D{1,4}/g)

console.log(result)
```

It will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the language in use.
In general, it will be a concatenation of 0 or more 4-character groups followed by 0-3 single characters.
Here is a possible formal definition for alphanumeric string: `([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Different languages might express this differently and possibly in a more compact way.